# The Linq Query Returns Errors

Tags: c#, angularjs, entity-framework, linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf rest service into angular js application . I am joining three tables records into a single record and displaying it in web application . I want when i click the button with account number it should returns user account information like account number , Money In ,Money Out ,Date and Account Balance etc . But i got following errors in google chrome network tab ..

**The server encountered an error processing the request. The exception message is 'The type 'HalifaxWCFProject.Transcation.AccountTransaction' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.'. See server logs for more details. The exception stack trace is:**

Here is the Class .

```
   public class AccountTransaction
    {
        public int? Account_Number { get; set; }

        public decimal? Deposit { get; set; }

        public decimal? Withdrawal { get; set; }

        public decimal? Account_Balance { get; set; }

        public string Date { get; set; }

    }
```

Here is the Linq Query .

```
 public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
    {
        var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
        {
                var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = w.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                    Date = w.Date
                }).Concat(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(d => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = d.Account_Number,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    Date = d.Date
                })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                .Concat(context.Current_Account_Details.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(e => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance
                }));
                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my angular js code .

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var app = angular.module('MyApp', [])
      app.controller('MyController', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
          $scope.IsVisible = false;
          $scope.Search = function () {
              var post = $http({
                  method: "GET",
                  url: "http://localhost:52098/HalifaxIISService.svc/TranscationDetails/" + encodeURIComponent($scope.Account_Number),
                  dataType: 'json',
                  headers: {
                      'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
                      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                  }
              });

              post.then(function (response) { // .success(function(data => .then(function(response
                  var data = response.data; // extract data from resposne
                  $scope.Customers = JSON.parse(data); // eval(data.d) => JSON.parse(data)
                  $scope.IsVisible = true;
              }, function (err) {
                  $window.alert(err);
              });
          }
      });
    </script>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
        Account Number:
        <input type="text" ng-model="Account_Number" />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="Search()" />
        <hr />
        <table style="border: solid 2px Green; padding: 5px;" ng-show="IsVisible">
            @*<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">*@
            <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                <th></th>
                <th> Account Number</th>
                 <th> Money In</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                 <th> Money Out</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Account Balance</th>

                <th></th>
                <th></th>

            </tr>
            <tbody ng-repeat="m in Customers">
                <tr style="height: 30px; background-color: skyblue; color: maroon;">
                    <td></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Number}}</span></td>
                     <td><span>{{m.Deposit| currency:"£"}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>

                    <td><span>{{m.Withdrawal | currency:"£"}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Date}}</span></td>
                    <td><span>{{m.Account_Balance| currency:"£"}}</span></td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the database [image]

Here is the Model.

Here is the Screen Shot On Debugging mode ..
[image]
[image]

Here is the result when i run the application[image]

Comment: have you tried with `Union` instead `Concat`?

Comment: All of your questions for last 2 days are the same.  You do not understand that **the statement of the problem is wrong**. Saying "I am **joining three tables records into a single record** ... it should returns user account information like account number , Money In ,Money Out ,*Date* and Account Balance" it is VERY WRONG. Because you may have **a lot of operations on different days** with this account, but you want ONE record with dates. Which of the date you should took from a lot of operations? Do you understand this? Also, `Concat` or `Union` are concating **ROWS**, NOT a **Columns**!!!

Comment: Or may be you want to say "joining three tables records into a single **VIEW** (table)". You must understan one thing:  "Single record" and "Single view" are **COMPLETELY DIFFERENT** things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code, Added all the properties of `AccountTransaction` add use `Union` instead `Concat`

`Union` will return distinct values but here your comparison is with reference of your items thus all items will be considered as different. `Concat` is equivalent to `Union All`

```
 public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
    {
        var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
        {
                var inOut = context.Current_Account_Deposit.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(w => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = w.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)0M,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)null,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)w.Amount,
                    Date = w.Date
                }).Union(context.Current_Account_Withdraw.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(d => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = d.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)0M,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)d.Amount,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)null,
                    Date = d.Date
                })).OrderBy(r => r.Date)
                .Union(context.Current_Account_Details.Where(x => x.Account_Number == accountNumber).Select(e => new AccountTransaction
                {
                    Account_Number = e.Account_Number,
                    Account_Balance = (decimal?)e.Account_Balance,
                    Deposit = (decimal?)0M,
                    Withdrawal = (decimal?)0M,
                    Date = DateTime.Now
                }));
                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                return js.Serialize(inOut); // return JSON string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank very much . Brilliant and great help @ programtreasures

Comment: `0M` is how you say `(decimal)0` because `M` is the suffix that means decimal